# not saving collaborator data to the table Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

in My Laravel 5.2 Application I have option add collaborators with the system. this is my ProjectCollaboratorController.php file

[jsfiddle.net/lilan2/2b1essdy/](http://jsfiddle.net/lilan2/2b1essdy/)

and this is the project_collaborator Model

```
class Collaboration extends Model{

    protected $table = 'project_collaborator';
    protected $fillable = ['project_id', 'collaborator_id'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'collaborator_id');
    }
public function scopeProject($query, $id) {
        return $query->where('project_id', $id);
    }
}
```

and this is the routes for collaborators route

```
Route::post('projects/{projects}/collaborators', [
    'uses' => 'ProjectCollaboratorsController@addCollaborator',
    'as'   => 'projects.collaborators.create',
    'middleware' => ['auth']
]);


Route::get('/project/{project}/collaborators', function($id){ 
       $collaborators = \App\Collaboration::all();
       $project = \App\Project::findOrFail($id);
       return view('collaborators.form',compact('collaborators','project')); 
    })->name('collaborators.form');
```

this is collaborator add form

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('projects.collaborators.create', $project->id) }}">
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('collaborator') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label> Add New </label>
            {!! mention()->asText('collaborator', old('collaborator'), 'users', 'username', 'form-control') !!}
            @if ($errors->has('collaborator'))
                <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('collaborator') }}</span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add User</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
 </form>
```

but when I clicked add collaborator button only page is refreshed not saving data to the table. how can fix this problem.

Comment: Maybe use function saveOrFail()?

Comment: function save...

Comment: apokryfos I did not get what do you mean? did you mean My route?

Comment: No any idea about this?

Comment: WHEN i COMMENT ROUTE 'as'   => 'projects.collaborators.create' system generated this error **Route [projects.collaborators.create] not defined.**

Comment: Nevermind I didn't notice the `as`

Comment: what is your suggestions

Comment: @Lilan can you please (a) add the `addCollaborator` method in the question itself and (b) share your `User` model relationships?